# Can reducing index length in Javascript associative array save memory

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a large Array (22,000 elements) of Associative Array elements in JavaScript. Do I need to worry about the length of the indices with regards to memory usage?

In other words, which of the following options saves memory? or are they the same in memory consumption?

Option 1:

```
  var student = new Array(); 
  for (i=0; i<22000; i++)
   student[i] = {
   "studentName": token[0],
   "studentMarks": token[1],
   "studentDOB": token[2]
   };
```

Option 2:

```
  var student = new Array(); 
  for (i=0; i<22000; i++)
   student[i] = {
   "n": token[0],
   "m": token[1],
   "d": token[2]
   };
```

I tried to test this on Google Chrome DevTools, but the numbers are inconsistent to make a decision. My best guess is that because the Array indices repeat, the browser can optimize memory usage by not repeating them for each student[i], but that is just a guess.

**Edit:**
To clarify, the problem is the following: a large array containing many small associative arrays. Does it matter using long index or short index when it comes to memory requirements.

**Edit 2:**
The 3N array approach that was suggested in the comments and @Joseph Myers is referring to is creating one array 'var student = []', with a size 3*22000, and then using student[0] for name, student[1] for marks, student[2] for DOB, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating such a large array in Javascript?

Comment: Your code shows that you are creating a large array (22,000 indices) containing many small associative arrays (only three keys). But your question's title seems to be asking how to make a large associative array more efficient (i.e., many keys). Which type of optimization do you actually wish to perform?

Comment: @Ed Heal: Actually, it is smaller than that, but I did not want to get the answer "computers are powerful, no body cares anymore". I am curious to know how memory is handled, especially for mobile-based browsers that have limited memory.

Comment: @df77 - If you are not being honest with the question how do you expect an honest answer?

Comment: @Joseph Myers: You are correct about the confusion. I meant optimizing the following: a large array (22,000 indices) containing many small associative arrays.

Comment: @Ed Heal: Does the answer change if it is 10,000 or 22,000 entries? I did not mean to offend any one.

Comment: @df777 - This comment differs from the comment to my question. What is exactly the nature of the problem? 22000 small associative arrays or summat else?

Comment: Off-topic just to note that javascript do not have the concept of 'associative arrays' , actually its an object in disguise and you will not get the associative_array.length etc and all attributes specific to an array.

Comment: @sakhunzai - Yes it does - An object has encapsulation. An "object" in Javascript is a mapping between keys and values (as yes some of those values can be functions). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_features_and_concepts and the bit about information hiding,

Comment: @Ed Heal And how do you get the associative array length ? any reference plz , thanks for your comments

Comment: @Ed Heal: The problem is the following: a large array containing many small associative arrays. Does it matter using long index or short index when it comes to memory requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main analysis of associative arrays' computational cost has to do with performance degradation as the number of elements stored increases, but there are some results available about performance loss as the key length increases.

In *Algorithms in C* by Sedgewick, it is noted that for some key-based storage systems the search cost does not grow with the key length, and for others it does. All of the comparison-based search methods depend on key length--if two keys differ only in their rightmost bit, then comparing them requires time proportional to their length. Hash-based methods *always* require time proportional to the key length (in order to compute the hash function).

Of course, the key takes up storage space within the original code and/or at least temporarily in the execution of the script.

The kind of storage used for JavaScript may vary for different browsers, but in a resource-constrained environment, using smaller keys would have an advantage, like still too small of an advantage to notice, but surely there are some cases when the advantage would be worthwhile.

P.S. My library just got in two new books that I ordered in December about the latest computational algorithms, and I can check them tomorrow to see if there are any new results about key length impacting the performance of associative arrays / JS objects.

Update: Keys like `studentName` take 2% longer on a Nexus 7 and 4% longer on an iPhone 5. This is negligible to me. I averaged 500 runs of creating a 30,000-element array with each element containing an object `{ a: i, b: 6, c: 'seven' }` vs. 500 runs using an object `{ studentName: i, studentMarks: 6, studentDOB: 'seven' }`. On a desktop computer, the program still runs so fast that the processor's frequency / number of interrupts, etc., produce varying results and the entire program finishes almost instantly. Once every few runs, the big key size actually goes faster (because other variations in the testing environment affect the result more than 2-4%, since the JavaScript timer is based on clock time rather than CPU time.) You can try it yourself here: http://dropoff.us/private/1372219707-1-test-small-objects-key-size.html

Your `3N` array approach (using array[0], array[1], and array[2] for the contents of the first object; and array[3], array[4], and array[5] for the second object, etc.) works much faster than any object method. It's five times faster than the small object method and five times faster plus 2-4% than the big object method on a desktop, and it is **11 times faster** on a Nexus 7.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. But if you can you please provide some benchmarks or previously-done tests, it would be excellent. I am mainly concerned about memory requirements, not comparison. However, it is nice to have learned about the comparison issues too.

Comment: it might take longer to parse longer keys, but they weight about the same in ram as one-letter keys given the repetitive nature of having many of the same keys in-use. If 20,000 keys were all long and different or all three chars and different, then the short keys would win. the savings comes from storing each key once, be they 3 or 20,000.

Comment: I'm looking for some benchmarks I've done before when I was doing an XML parser for JavaScript several years ago. It used many small objects for storing properties of each HTML tag, and basically did the same thing as creating an array of 22,000 numerically-indexed elements each containing a small object.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is insignificant, so the answer is **no**. This sort of thing would barely even fall under **[micro optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/micro-optimization/info)**. You should always opt for **most readable** solutions when in such dilemmas. The cost of maintaining code from your second option outweighs any (if any) performance gain you could get from it.

What you should do though is use the literal for creating an array.

`[]` instead of `new Array()`. (just a side note)

A better approach to solve your problem would probably be to find a way to load the data in parts, implementing some kind of pagination (I assume you're not doing heavy computations on the client).

Comment: Can you please point me to some benchmarks or previously-done tests to support your answer? I am guessing from experience, the Desktop is so powerful it would not matter, but what if it is a mobile browser with limited memory, or it is a million records I am dealing with?

Comment: Yeah, some references will be great

Comment: The gain would really be non-existent, either way. If you need to deal with such huge datasets on a platform with limited resource, you should look into ways of splitting (loading) the data in smaller groups.

Comment: I thought about creating one array 'var student = []', with a size 3*22000, and then using student[0] for name, student[1] for marks, student[2] for DOB, etc. Will this solution, for example, occupy the same amount of memory? I am guessing this will use smaller memory but create bad readability!

Comment: @d777 your 3n-array idea is an extremely excellent optimization for a lot of data. The same test that took a few seconds using arrays on a Nexus 7 ran almost instantly using the array method that you describe (using only one array and storing properties in groups of three adjacent array elements).

Comment: @ Joseph Myers: Thanks indeed. I was looking for such bench marks. It tells me that both memory and processing are affected by the choices we make in building the array.